# Image Rollover the text goes out of box when decrease the screen size?

Tags: wordpress

[Text Goes Out Of The Box (Blue Background 2nd Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7MfT.jpg)

Please Check the error:
[Error Still Exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv2mR.jpg)

Comment: Fix outer container

Comment: thanks for your time, the site is on wordpress and very limited options to edit it.

Comment: url - addon.bigfaction.com

Comment: So you can access its style sheet or not because you need edit that if you want to fix this

Comment: yes i can access the style sheet

Comment: Please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to you css file

```css
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1199px)
   { 
     .home .vc_column_container { margin-bottom: 20px; width: 50%; }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great Help.

Comment: you can mark this question as fixed if it works for you and vote ... :)

Comment: the solution you provided worked but not working everywhere. I have edited the question and put an image beside " Please Check the error: ", please have a look.

Comment: what you mentioned earlier was fixed you can apply the same for other areas as well...